# For which of the following equations does it exist $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that the equation is satisfied

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For which of the following equations does it exist $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that the equation is satisfied

Lets say you have the equations:

> #1) $735s+847t=-28$
>
> #2) $33649s+3059t=1$
>
> #3) $825s+315t=5$
>
> #4) $3454s+4666t=3$

How would you proceed to figure out which of them are satisfied for integer $s,t$?
Brute-forcing with large numbers like that seems almost impossible at least if you have limited time and only a calculator.

Comment: you need to pick one equation or a pair of equations?

Comment: Instead of "true" you mean "satisfiable", right ?

Comment: Yeah I mean satisfiable. This example comes from a midterm test, and in theory: 1 must be satisfiable, but all 4 can be satisfiable. (Only #1 is satisfiable in this example, but all 4 equations could be satisfiable in another example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equation of the form $\ ax+by=n\ $ with integers $a,b$ and $n$ ($a$ and $b$ not both $0$) has an integer solution if and only if $\ \gcd(a,b)|n$. In this case, there are infinite many integer solutions, in other words infinite many integer pairs $(x/y)$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can express those 4 equations as a linear combination such as $eq1-4*eq3-3eq4+eq2=0$, so you get:

$735s+847t-4(825s+315t)+3(3454s+4666t)-(33649s+3059t)=0 \implies -19987s + 12199t = 0 \implies s=\frac{12199}{19987}t=\frac{1109}{1817}t$

So the condition is meet for all multiples of t being 1817 you'd get s, i.e:

$t=1817 , s=1109$

$t=2*1817 , s=2*1109$

$...$

$t=n*1817 , s=n*1109$